# Proof of linear transform being a basis for set $L(U,V)$ meyer's book

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: proof]

Hi, I have trouble understanding what the author means and how he extracts the information from the areas of the proof I highlighted. In the first rectangle he means $B_L=(B_{11}, B_{12}, ... B_{1m}..., B_{nm}) $ so it's a basis with size $m \cdot n$ ?
Then in the second rectangle, why $B_{ji}=0 $ for $j\neq k$ and $v_i$ for $j=k$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes, $B_L$ has $m*n$ elements.

  Imagine $U=\mathbb R^n$ and $V=\mathbb R^m$ and pick the standard basis', then the $m\times n$ matrices where exactly one entry is $1$ and all other are $0$ form a basis for $\mathcal L(U,V)$.
- We want to calculate $B_{ji}(u_k)$, where $u_k$ is the k'th element of $\mathcal B$. We calculate $[u_k]_{\mathcal B}$, which is the $n$-vector which has entry $1$ at position $k$ and is $0$ elsewhere, so $[u_k]_{\mathcal B}=\begin{pmatrix}\xi_1,\xi_2,\ldots,\xi_n\end{pmatrix}^T$ with $\xi_j=\delta_{jk}=\begin{cases}1& j=k\\0&j\neq k\end{cases}$. From the definition, $B_{ji}(u_k)=\xi_j v_i = \begin{cases}v_i &j=k\\0&j\neq k\end{cases}$.

As for the question why $[u_k]_{\mathcal B} = (0~0~\dots~\underbrace{1}_{\text{ k}}~0~\dots 0)^T$, we calculate $[u]_{\mathcal B}$ by decomposing $u$ with respect to $\mathcal B$: $$u=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i u_i$$ Then $[u]_{\mathcal B}=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n)^T$ by definition. Since $u_k$ is an element of $\mathcal B$, we obtain the result.

Let's add an example: We consider $U=\mathcal P_2(\mathbb R)$, the vector space of polynomial with real coefficients of degree $\leq 2$. $\mathcal B=\{\,1,1+X,1+X+X^2\,\}$ is a basis of $U$. If we take $p=1+2X^2$, a vector in $U$, we can calculate its coordinates with respect to $\mathcal B$:
$$p=2(1+X+X^2) -2(X+1) + 1$$
therefore $[p]_{\mathcal B}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&2\end{pmatrix}^T$. The basis-element $1+X$ has coordinates $[1+X]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\end{pmatrix}^T$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the author only makes the assumption that $sum{h_{ji}B_{ji}}=0$ he didn't state that $u_k$ is a unitary basis, I thought that he meant a more general basis and not the standard unitary of a m-dim space.

Comment: @bigboss We don't need a unitary basis for this.

Comment: But when you force $ξ_k=1$ for j=k don't you force $u_k$ to be a unitary basis? It seems that either I misunderstood something in the theory or I am confused right now. For example for $R^3$ exist many basis, but ${(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ is the unitary ortho canonical.

Comment: @bigboss I edited my answer to adress this. I guess you misunderstood the definition of the coordinate map $[\_]_{\mathcal B}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this is the part I couldn't get, because I saw $u_k$ as the k-th component of B basis. So we write the component of the basis $u_k$ as a linear combination of the basis of B. Am I correct? Well that was a very strange practice for me and not obvious because I really couldn't forsee any usability in doing so in general. Two more questions if I may. I want to clarify that $B_L$ is a set of n*m vectors correct? Not a matrix, because you said m*n elements. And finally what's the difference in notation between $B_ji$ and $B_{ji}(u)$? First implies a matrix and the 2nd product?

Comment: In other words what Bji without an argument represents. What's the meaning of Bji  without (u). What it is equal to.

Comment: @bigboss The usefullness of $[\_]_{\mathcal B}$ is the following: It provides an isomorphism from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. It enables you to apply a linear transformation $\Phi$ to a vector $v$ by multiplying the transformation matrix of  $\Phi$ w.r.t $\mathcal B$ to $[v]_{\mathcal{B}}$.\\\ $B_{\mathcal L}$ is a set of $nm$ *linear maps* from $U$ to $V$. It is a basis of $\mathcal L(U,V)$, so it should contain vectors of $\mathcal L(U,V)$, which are maps. In my example above, $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ can be identified with the set of $n\times m$-matrices.

Comment: @bigboss $B_{ji}$ is a vector in $\mathcal L(U,V)$, i.e. a linear map $U\to V$. $B_{ji}(u)$ is the evaluation of said map at $u$, which is a vector in $V$. If you have further questions concerning those topics, I suggest that we  [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82547/discussion-between-babelfish-and-bigboss).

Answer (score 0):

$\mathscr L(U,V)$ should have dimension $mn$.  So that's how many elements in the basis.

Next, $B_{i,j}(u)=\xi_jv_i$ where $\xi=(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)=[u]_{\mathcal B}$, by definition. 
  That is (as the author states), "pick off the $j$th coordinate of $u$ and attach it to $v_i$".

Now note that for $u_k\in\mathcal B$, $[u_k]_{\mathcal B}=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ , where the $1$ is in the $k$th coordinate.

Your statement follows.

Comment: Why $[u_k]_{\mathcal B}=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots,0)$ , I mean the author never stated we use the unitary basis. That's why I am struggling it seems.

Comment: @bigboss To calculate $[v]_{\mathcal B}$, you decompose $v$ into the basis $\mathcal B$ and put the coefficients of the decomposition into a vector. Since $u_k$ is itself a member of the basis, you get the decomposition $u_k = 0 u_1 + 0u_2 + \dots + 1 u_k + 0 u_{k+1} + 0 u_n$ which leads to the above vector.

Comment: A basis relative to itself is...  the standard basis...

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't think it this way. I couldn't forsee this having any usability, but seems it is useful in proofs!

Comment: It comes up pretty often.

Comment: Thanks, also can you explain the difference to me in notation with $B_{ji}$ and $B_{ji}(u)$ ? What's the meaning of it without an argument?

Comment: $\mathcal B_{ji}$ stands for the linear transformation (from $\mathcal  U$ to $\mathcal V$).

Comment: So when he writes $\sum_{ij}η_{ji}B_{ji}=0$ what's the meaning of it inside there? What it is equal to for example?I mean as an entity, inside this sum, $B_{ji}=?$

Comment: There he's showing they are linearly independent as vectors in $\mathcal L(U,V)$...The $B_{ji}$ are linear transformations,  but also vectors in $\mathcal L(U,V)$...