# The set of linear functions from $F^n$ to $W$ is identified with $\{W^n\}$, where $F$ is a field and $W$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of linear functions from $F^n$ to $W$ is identified with $W^n =$ the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $W$, where $F$ is a field and $W$ is a vector space.

What does "the set is identified with $W^n$" mean? Should I show there is a bijective relation between these two sets? Is there any simple example that helps to understand their relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a natural bijection $\Psi$ between the two sets: if $f\colon F^n\longrightarrow W$ is a linear map, let$$\Psi(f)=\bigl(f(e_1),f(e_2),\ldots,f(e_n)\bigr),$$where $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is the standard basis of $F^n$. Then $\Psi$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have showed that $\Psi$ is injective, but I'm stuck on proving $\Psi$ is surjective. Should I define $f:F^c \to W$ with the rule $f(e_i) = y_i$ for $i=1,2, \dots, c$? It seems not enough if I define $f$ with only this rule

Comment: @user398843 The map $\Psi$ is linear. So, since $\dim F^n=\dim W$,$$\psi\text{ injective}\iff\Psi\text{ surjective}\iff\Psi\text{ bijective.}$$

Comment: From which we can know that $\dim F^n = \dim W$?

Comment: @user398843 My mistake. What I should have written was that both spaces ($W^n$ and the space of all linear maps from $F^n$ to $W$) have the same dimension: $n\times\dim W$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it means that for each linear functional there exists a $n-$tuple corresponding to that and vice versa.

For example, if you consider a linear function from $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ must be of the form $f(x,y)=ax+by=(a,b) \cdot (x,y)$. So corresponding to $f$, there is $2-$tuple $(a,b)$.

For the converse, if you start with an ordered pair $(a,b)$, then you can use that to create a linear function $f$ (as stated).

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\operatorname{dim}W\lt\infty$.

$\mathcal L(F^n,W)$ is in fact a vector space of dimension $n\cdot \operatorname{dim}W$.

Any two finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.

$W^n$ is also a vector space of dimension $n\cdot \operatorname {dim}W$.

So in particular we have a bijection between the two.

Not sure about the general case...

Comment: Why are $\mathcal L(F^n,W)$ and $W^n$ of dimension $n\cdot \operatorname {dim}W$?

Comment: See this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2900581/403337